# Question on in-laws immediate family if our families are close

Tags: verb-stacking

We all consider our family to include the families married into our family, but I've always wondered what to call my Uncle Ted's mother. Ted is married to my Aunt Kim, who is my mother's sister.

Is she my grandmother like my other uncles' mother, or would she be a great aunt?

Answer (score 2):

Strictly speaking, she is simply a relative by marriage. In less close families, she would be referred as your "Uncle Ted's mother" or, if Ted and Kim have children, your "cousins' grandmother," but you could instead say she is your "aunt by marriage" or "great-aunt by marriage." 
Your grandmother is someone from whom you are directly descended, the mother of one of your parents (unless your grandfather remarried).